# github PR showing every past commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We recently switched workflow. Our (new) repository on github has 2 branches: `master` and `develop`.

`master` is protected from direct pushes, only PRs are merged. `develop` is where all the fun happens.

Feature branches are merged back into `develop`

```sh
git merge --no-ff feat/some_feat
```

and releases are cut from some commit on develop or maybe its tip. Then a PR is open and if everything checks out fine, `release` gets merged into `master` and `master` into `develop` to avoid detachment.

Now, we noticed that every every PR we open, it shows, in the commits, every commit ever made. The number of changed files is correct, but we get an enormous list of commits after few releases.

Why is that? Are we misusing git? Probably yes.

Comment: This happens if you `git rebase` the branch carelessly. I have found it to be a good practice to `git rebase master` on the branch before pushing a PR.

Comment: @tripleee It does not seem to make any difference even if we do not rebase anything until prior to push the PR as you suggest. Commits are piling up. The only solution is to reset `develop` but by doing that we loose history of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've found the "problem"... Now the history, scroll to the bottom for the solution (sort of).

So, we wanted to have the convenience of a linear history on `master` with preserving history of commits on `develop`.

This causes `develop` to advance WRT `master` indefinetely so that `master` "never" catches up with `develop` (in the sense of commit history). When opening a PR from `develop` you get this huge list of commits (again, the number of changed files is correct, so no real problem there). This is a GUI incovenience.

The resulting graph is something like this (on a test repository)

[image]

The green line coming out from `master` is a hotfix which is merged back into `develop` prior to creating a new PR. Other lines stemming from `develop` are features.

The workflow, for interested parties, is as follow:

Feature:

```sh
$ git checkout -b new-feature develop
... work, commit, work, commit
$ git rebase develop
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge --no-ff new feature
$ git push develop
$ git branch -d new-feature
```

Release (from tip of develop or the last commit ready for release)

```sh
$ git checkout -b release/x.y.z (develop|045c89)
... work, commit, work, commit
$ git tag -a x.y.z -m "new release x.y.z" 
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge release/x.y.z
$ git push --follow-tags develop
$ git branch -d release/x.y.z
```

then we open a PR on github from `develop` and squash it into `master`. It could be from `release` as well, I think.

Back to our local we pull/fetch from origin and merge `master` into `develop`. This step is necessary otherwise we get an 'unable to automatically merge' in the next PR.

Hotfixes are the same as releases but stem from master.

Of course, it is possible to push directly to `master` after a relase/hotfix by doing:

```sh
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash x.y.z
... commit with something like "version x.y.z"
$ git push
```

So that the branch protection for linear history on github does not complain.

Here is a screenshot of a PR on github... Only 4 files were actually changed. The actual commits for these changes are the last 3 in the huge list. All the others are the previous ones :(

[image: PR on github]

SOLUTION (sort of):

after PR is merged, locally do:

```sh
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -B develop
$ git push --force origin HEAD
```

This will reset `develop` so that both `master` and `develop` will be even. We lose history on `develop` but we don't have a massive list of 'commits'. This makes me wonder why we need `develop` in the first place, we could migrate to the 'trunk' workflow of to github flow.