# GitHub PR showing lots of unnecessary commits from other developers

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I know there are already similar questions in StackOverflow but after lots of searching and struggling, I am forced to ask this question.

We have a master branch on GitHub and other developers create feature branches to develop their features. Once the feature is developed then they **merge and squash** it via PR request. This is normal workflow and working expected.

Now issues occur sometimes when I am creating PR requests (e.g. feature1 ) to master then in files changed it shows lots of other files which I have not touched.
This I assume because feature1 is in past compared to the master.
Usually, if do, merge via command

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
git push --force-with-lease
```

afterwards unnecessary changes from PR goes away. ---> This works

However, if I do same with a different way (git pull ) way then these necessary file changes doesn't go. I ran following command

```
git pull origin master
```

Just to reconfirm, I ran this command again and it shows below response

```
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

after that I do git push

```
git push
```

and in PR I can see succesful last commit as
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/.......reponame

however, I can still see lots of changes in the "Files Changes" tab. My expectation is as changes are already merged from master the unnecessary files should go away or my understanding is wrong?

**Edit**: As I cannot reproduce this, I am looking for the most preferred way to creating a pull request from a long-running feature branch so I don't end up in a situation like this. git pull seems to be not the best way so do I always need to go to git rebase?

I found this issue is not unique to me and it is questioned many times but there is no proper answer to this.

- [github PR showing every past commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937999/github-pr-showing-every-past-commits)
- [Github PR is showing older commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319959/github-pr-is-showing-older-commits)

I expect a clear solution to overcome this issue forever.

Comment: Typically this situation arises because when a PR is finished you are not actually merging the feature branch — you're telling GitHub to "rebase and merge" or "squash and merge", which are not merges. Is that the case in this workflow?

Comment: Also I don't understand what the `git pull origin master` is intended to do. Can you add (to your question) what the response from Git is the first time you say that?

Comment: @matt yes in PR we do "squash and merge" if everything is ok but I see unecessary changes when PR is in "open" status itself and I feel if I do "squash and merge" it will overwrite in master unnecessary...

Comment: with git pull origin master, I wanted to merge remote master changes in my feature branch.

Comment: And did you? Did Git say it had made a merge commit in your feature branch? Add that response to your question, please.

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask another question. Have you ever done a pull request using this feature branch before? In other words, are you re-using the same feature branch for multiple PRs?

Comment: @matt i have updated the question. 
PR gets deleted usually if squash & merge is successful. So everytime we create new PRs

Comment: Usually, yes, but I'm asking about this one. A long-lived feature branch is a typical source of these issues. I'm just trying to establish what you're seeing so that I can explain it.

Comment: @matt no issues :) yes this branch also created few days ago freshly. thanks for your help

Comment: And are you sure this branch was created off of `master`? You didn't create it off of some existing feature branch? There isn't, alternatively, some other branch `development` or something that you aren't telling us about? You really are branching directly from `master` and requesting to merge to `master` when you make your pull request?

Comment: @matt i am really not sure if this branch is created via master.( ideally, it should) But does this matter as at the end I am anyway pulling recent changes from master and merging it

Comment: flow is simple, there is master branch --> i created feature branch out of this --> after 5-6 days once i done with my changes --> i tried git pull origin master --> i created PR request to merge to master--> and here in PR it shows many changes which i didn't develop in my feature branch

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the phenomenon based on the information you've given.

Comment: "i am really not sure if this branch is created via master" Well, if it _wasn't_ then your results become more probable. How can you not be sure? Look at the history and find out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236476/discussion-between-sharad-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is [the one described in the Git FAQ about long-running branches and squash merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge).  The FAQ outlines the reasons behind this in great detail, but roughly, you cannot use squash merges and long-running feature branches and expect good results.  What you're seeing is a common consequence of trying to do so.

If you want your PR branch to be up to date, you'll have to rebase it, or you'll have to stop merging with squash merges to your main branch.

Comment: Please see the comments. That is what I was angling at, but it takes two long running branches to elicit that problem, and the OP insists there is no second long running branch. I think the OP is concealing some important additional information.

Comment: The feature branch sounds like it's the second long running branch in this case, since it's needing to be rebased, even though it may not end up lasting an actual long time.

Comment: The OP says not. Read the comments please.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't. :) I failed to notice the OP's "i am really not sure if this branch is created via master". This could be the heart of the matter.